# how to print the c-zech character in prn file in zpl printer GT800 zpl?

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I have a Prn file which has some English and Czech character. English character are printing well but Czech character are missing while printing. I have a GT 800 ZPL printer. what should I do?

I know that to print Unicode character I can use utf-8 base encoding, but still I don't get Unicode character printed.

```
^XA
^CI28
^FO60,75
^ASN,36,20^FH^FDPo_c4_8det^FS
^FO60,195
^ASN,36,20^FH^FDkus_c5_af^FS
c5af
^CI0
^FO10,15
^A0N,38,28^FDPART_NO^FS
^FT20,178
^A0N,28,38^FDOPER_ID^FS
^XZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that your Printer has the correct fonts and firmware,
the ZPL looks ok for me
[Label](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=12&width=3&height=3&units=inches&index=0&zpl=%5EXA%20%5ECI28%20%5EFO60%2C75%20%5EASN%2C36%2C20%5EFH%5EFDPo_c4_8det%5EFS%20%5EFO60%2C195%20%5EASN%2C36%2C20%5EFH%5EFDkus_c5_af%5EFS%20c5af%20%5ECI0%20%5EFO10%2C15%20%5EA0N%2C38%2C28%5EFDPART_NO%5EFS%20%5EFT20%2C178%20%5EA0N%2C28%2C38%5EFDOPER_ID%5EFS%20%5EXZ)